# Problem while computing and plotting a table

Tags: graphing-functions

I want to create a list of numbers, by computing an integral of something divided by a function, and then plot it.

```
liste = Table[Re[Exp[-NIntegrate[h[t],{t, -k, 0},
Method -> {Automatic,"SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}]]/f[k]], {k, 1, 100}]
```

The result if something of the form {{a1},{a2},{a3},...}, and not like {a1,a2,a3,...}. So when I want to plot it

```
ListPlot[liste]
```

It returns me

[image]Why does it not return me something like {a1,a2,...}, so that I can plot the list with k on the x-axis?

Comment: you can use Flatten[] on the final list

Comment: Oh I didn't know this, it simply works!! Thanks a lot!